# Running features in parallel by tags in Karate

Tags: karate

I have a end to end test suite with features marked with @e2e tag. The features are within different modules namely WNG, DTC, FFD with their own tags(like @e2eWNG, @e2eDTC, @e2eFFD) along with @e2e. Each of the modules can run independently and I wish to parallelise the test execution. For example tags with @e2eWNG can run on a single thread, @e2eDTC can run on another thread and so on.

Right now I just run all tests with tags @e2e and this is sequential.

I had a look at https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/DemoTestParallel.java as an example but I could not figure out how to separate the threads by tags.

I tried doing this based on a solution mentioned here - [Is it possible to generate Cucumber HTML Reports with Karate's JUnit5 fluent API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57681467/is-it-possible-to-generate-cucumber-html-reports-with-karates-junit5-fluent-api) and this is what I did in my test runner class

```
Results DTC = Runner.path("classpath:").tags("@e2eDTC").reportDir("target/cucumber-html-reports").parallel(1);
Results WNG = Runner.path("classpath:").tags("@e2eWNG").reportDir("target/cucumber-html-reports").parallel(1);
Results FFD = Runner.path("classpath:").tags("@e2eFFD").reportDir("target/cucumber-html-reports").parallel(1);

assertTrue(DTC.getErrorMessages(), DTC.getFailCount() == 0); 
assertTrue(WNG.getErrorMessages(), WNG.getFailCount() == 0); 
assertTrue(FFD.getErrorMessages(), FFD.getFailCount() == 0); 

generateReport(DTC.getReportDir());
generateReport(WNG.getReportDir());
generateReport(FFD.getReportDir());
```

But I do understand this is again sequential. Just wanted to know if there is way we can parallelise the execution separated by tags. I may be missing something but any suggestions would be really helpful.

Answer (score -1):

> run all tests with tags @e2e and this is sequential.

If you are using the parallel-runner with threads > 1, this should not happen.

In my opinion there is no need for you to run each tag on a different thread. Just use one parallel runner and 3 tags. This is what all teams do. If you have some tests that really don't mix with other tests in the suite (which is an anti-pattern and you should fix), you can look at the `@parallel=false` tag: https://github.com/intuit/karate#parallelfalse

Comment: Thanks for this @Peter. I tried with what you suggested, made threads=3 and marked the failing tests with @parallel=false. But that did not help as I saw failures in other tests in the next run. The tests are mutually exclusive but I think its the way the tests are written, within WNG for example, a single thread running tests sequentially is fine. Same way with the other modules.  But I was hoping to find a way to run features parallely seperated by tags. I also tried 3 different test runners calling them from maven commandline. But that does it sequentially as well which was expected.

Comment: @Mihir karate cannot help you here. you can try managing threads yourself using a Java executor, something like this: https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-junit4/src/test/java/com/intuit/karate/junit4/files/JarLoadingTest.java#L102

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. I will look into the java executor. I am also looking at making this happen at CI/CD where I can configure parallel runners for each of the tags. That could possible solve the issue as well. Thanks once again :)

Comment: @Mihir in my opinion the "issue" is that your tests are not independent. I strongly suggest you fix the root cause. CI / CD and all that will work - but you forever will be feeling the pain and uncertainty whether your tests failed because of a parallel timing issue or something else. just my 2c